# NGINX Yii2 убрать из ссылок ndex.php?r=site%2F

Tags: yii2, nginx, docker

Использую Docker для сборки контейнера с целью локальной разработки на Yii2.

**nginx.conf:**

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80;

    server_name mysite.test;
    root        /var/www/html/web;
    index       index.php;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**Проблема:**

Ссылки работают только в таком виде:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php?r=site%2Fabout

Уже третий час рыскаю по интернету в поисках решения, но так и не смог найти ответа. Иные пути реализации не рассматриваю.

Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Answer (score 0):

В файле "config/web.php" нужно раскомментировать следующий код:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
    ],
],
```